# jQuery .prop is not working for me I'm trying to select a checkbox on document load but it is not working

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox, prop

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.check').each(function() {
    ${this}.prop('checked',true).checkboxradio("refresh");
    console.log($(this).attr("value"));
  });
});
```

I used the above code with HTML as below

```
<input type="checkbox" class = "check" value="one">
```

Comment: What language is `${variable}`?  Try `$(this).prop`.  Also check the browser console for errors, you're probably getting `Unexpected token '{'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `'checked', 'checked'`
Here is an example, if you put inside your document.ready it will check all checkbox with the class `check`.

```
$(".check").each(function (){
    $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

   $(".check").each(function (){
         $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');
     });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input check" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="flexCheckDefault">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
        Default checkbox
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is best practice, but `,true` also works for jquery .prop checked. Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y79qLbws/

Comment: if is the best practive why change it? lol

Comment: I'm highlighting the fact that you've stated *You **need** to do `'checked', 'checked'`* when, in fact, you don't *need to* and OPs code would work fine if they simply used `$(this)` instead of `${ }`.  I've voted question to close as a typo :)

Comment: I tried with$(this) but didn't worked. It worked with $(this).prop('checked','checked');

Comment: ye sometimes the ````('checked', true)```` doenst work, i still cant figure out why. Good it helped you. =)